# Entity Framework won't allow creation of an object when SQL Server Row Level Security is active

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, row-level-security

We have implemented row level security in SQL Server, which works great. Only users who have access to certain rows can see them. When we implement Entity Framework 6, though, a user creates a record and gets `Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)`. Based on my research of others having this issue, it's due to Optimistic Concurrency in EF. This apparent safeguard assumes it should be able to select back a record that you just inserted, while that is not true. Everything works fine in SQL Server.

Is there a way to stop EF's requirement of selecting a recently inserted record? Based on other answers, I saw that it can be done, but then the `INSERT` would fail silently. This is obviously not useful.

Comment: Does a single-row insert fail, or only batch inserts?  Do you have database-generated columns?

Comment: I'm saving a single object, but EF must be saving the object graph. Yes, we created the entire schema in SQL Server with scripts. A single-row insert succeeds when we do it via SQL, just not EF.